# Updating LiveCode progress bar gives an error

Tags: progress-bar, livecode

I want to load a list of files and update a progress bar, but I get an error when updating the thumb position.  The code is OK When I click the apply button - what causes the error?

```
-- update the progress bar with current file number
on set_progress new_value
  set the thumbposition of "progress" to new_value
end set_progress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to specify that "progress" is a scrollbar control.  Refer to it as

```
scrollbar "progress"
```

instead of just

```
"progress"
```

The working handler is;

```
-- update the progress bar on screen
on set_progress new_value
   set the thumbposition of scrollbar "progress" to new_value
end set_progress
```

Comment: Ah!  First time with scroll bars, but now I know !